# How to Start my application Map Activity in a Different App?

Tags: android, android-intent, maps

in my application I have an activity with google map fragment.
I want all other applications which have intent to open a location with other apps , show my application in list of apps that can open their location with, like Maps or Waze.

I make action in my manifest but it dosen't work , what is wrong and what can I do?

```
<activity
        android:name=".Activitys.AddressActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.actions.SEARCH_ACTION"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.APP_MAPS"/>
            <data android:mimeType="text/plain"/>
            <data android:mimeType="image/*"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the intent filter that Google map  is using :

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
    <data android:scheme="https" android:host="maps.google.com" />
    <data android:scheme="geo" />
</intent-filter>
```

Comment: @MohammadHadi what is the link that you are trying to open?

Comment: I want other apps can open my app as intent to open a location on map.

Comment: Now in 2023 you can't have more than one tag with "category android:name". The same is for "data android:scheme"